# Primary and Foreign Key in DW tables

Tags: data-warehouse

I've read that dimension tables hold the primary key and and fact tables contain the foreign key which references the primary key of Dimension tables.

Now the confusion I am having is this  - suppose I have an ETL pipeline which populates the dimension table (let's say customer) from a source (say another DB). Let's assume this is a frequently changing table and has over 200 columns. How do I incorporate these changes in the dimension tables? I want to have only the latest record for each customer (type 1 SCD) in the DWH.

One thing what I could do is delete the row in the dimension table and re-insert the new updated row. But this approach won't work because of the primary key - foreign key constraint (which will not allow me to delete the record).

Should I write an update statement with all 200 columns in the ETL script? Or is there any other approach?

Comment: Yes, just update the dimension record

Comment: Merge-> update and insert

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking you just need to update the fields that changed. But the cost of updating all in a single record is probably similar (assuming it’s row based storage), and it’s probably easier to write.

You can’t delete and re-insert, as the new row will have a new PK and old facts will no longer be linked.